# Material-UI Popper remains visible when `open` prop is set to `true`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popper.js

I'm using Material-UI `Popper` [component](https://material-ui.com/api/popper/) and using it with its `keepMounted` prop set.

The issue I'm having is that when the Popper's component `open` prop is  `false` the popper goes of out of the window boundaries but remain visible.

**Q:** What approach should I use to ensure that the popper is not visibled/displayed when the Popper component's `open` is false?
I've looked into it (see below for more details) but without success.

I've setup a [small repro](https://389w75jpom.codesandbox.io/) and example code here: 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/389w75jpom

Scroll to the bottom when the tooltip/popper "isn't shown" and notice that it's still visible. Clicking the button toggles the value of the Popper component's `open` property.

I'm hoping for the popper to be hidden when `open` is `false` while still using `keepMounted`. I would prefer if it wouldn't be shown at all (e.g `display: none`) not just go out of sight.

From Material-UI docs, I’ve seen that `popper.js` modifiers can be passed using the `modifiers` prop and look at `modifiers~hide` specifically. 
In [the doc](https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html#modifiers..hide) it's mentioned that the `hide` modifier:

> [...] will set a `x-out-of-boundaries` attribute which can be used to hide with a CSS selector the popper when its reference is out of boundaries.

As per the doc this modifier should be enabled by default but it seems that the `x-out-of-boundaries` attribute **doesn't seem to be applied** to the popper container `div` at all.
So I haven't been able to rely on a CSS selector in this case.

I've also found this GH issue that I believe led to the implementation of the `hide` modifier.

I've tried to pass down [1] to the modifier a `hidePopper` function similar to the one suggested [in the same GH issue here](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/52#issuecomment-239204968) to detect when the popper goes in and out of the boundaries and set its style accordingly. Here's a fork of the previous repro with the code updated to reflect this:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/jvr6oy95j3

But the `boundaries` attribute is not present on the `data` object passed to the function (see the console logs) when testing here:
https://jvr6oy95j3.codesandbox.io/

Sorry if I'm missing something and would really appreciate any guidance on this. Thanks

[1] via the `hide.fn` modifier attribute.